# Cant send retrofit 2.0 multipart request with parameters with the same keys

Tags: android, retrofit

I need to send a multipart request using the retrofit 2.0 with image and some key-value parameters: `"key1" - "parameter1"` , `"key2" - "parameter2"` etc. But there are parameters with the same key:  `"somepar[]" - "text1"` , `"somepar[]" - "text2"` ... And i cant use `@PartMap` in this structure:

```
@Multipart
@POST(myUrlPart)
Call<ClassEntity> myRequest(@Header("Authorization") String authHeader,
                                @Part("image\"; filename=\"image.png\"") RequestBody image,
                                @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> params);
```

because Map<> cant store multiple values with the same key. 
And i cant use

```
@Part("somepar[]") List<String> mylist
```

or

```
@Part("somepar[]") String[] myArray
```

because it will send key-value `"somepar[]" - "{"1","2","3"}"`, not the `"somepar[]" = "1"`  ,  `"somepar[]" = "2"`  , `"somepar[]" = "3"`.

Please help, how to make such a request.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, this problem was solved in new verions of retrofit library (2.1.0 version at the moment writing this post). This code will be work correctly and send data correctly:

```
@Part("somepar[]") List<String> mylist
```

Thanks.

Comment: Perfect answer.